# Canvas toDataURL() method is saving low resolution image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I have made a polygonal background generator using HTML5 canvas over at:

http://codepen.io/rfalor/pen/LhinJ

This is the relevant code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
```

When an user clicks the canvas, and subsequently "Prepare Image", the image that is saved on right click is of low resolution(300px x 150px), instead of the canvas resolution. How do I allow the user to save a higher resolution image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're sizing the canvas using css rather than the `width` and `height` properties of the canvas element. When you do that you're only *stretching* the canvas not increasing the coordinate space of the element.

I added the following to your code

```
canvas.width = 700;
canvas.height = 396;
```

Then I had to change your randomize function a bit to accept a number since it wont always be 500;

```
function randomize(num) {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    return a;
}
```

And you can now call your `lineTo`'s like this

```
ctx.lineTo(randomize(canvas.width), randomize(canvas.height));
ctx.lineTo(randomize(canvas.width), randomize(canvas.height));
```

However I realize you probably want it to be *more* than the width and height so you don't see the edges of the shapes but I figure you can fix that up.

### **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/bsaQ8/)**

**Fully modified code below.**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

function randomize(num) {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    return a;
}

function sides() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    return a;
}

function getRndColor() {
    var r = 255 * Math.random() | 0,
        g = 255 * Math.random() | 0,
        b = 255 * Math.random() | 0,
        alpha = 0.1; //Math.random().toFixed(1);
    var final = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + alpha + ')';
    return final;
}

$('*').click(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $('button').show();
});

$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).css('left', '-400px');
    $('h3').text("Right click and save a beautiful background!");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
    $('#canvasImg').css('border', '5px solid black');
    $('#canvas').hide();
    $('#canvasImg').show();
});

if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var left = true;

    canvas.width = 700;
    canvas.height = 396;

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            if (left) {
                ctx.moveTo(0, randomize(canvas.height));
                left = false;
            } else {
                ctx.moveTo(randomize(canvas.width), 0);
                left = true;
            }
            ctx.lineTo(randomize(canvas.width), randomize(canvas.height));
            ctx.lineTo(randomize(canvas.width), randomize(canvas.height));
            ctx.fillStyle = getRndColor();
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```